# Attempting an Excel IF statement with a range of possible outcomes

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

OK, so I'm trying to create an excel fitness tracker that calculates body fat percentages from the measurements that are input. That part is good and works fine, and I have it set so that if there is no data in the dependent cells, it displays N/A. I then have a cell that I put a formula in as follows:

```
=IF(C28<=5%,"Body Builder", IF(C28<13%,"Athletic", IF(C28<17%,"Fit", IF(C28<25%,"Average", IF(C28>=26%,"Obese","No Data Yet")))))
```

Essentially, I want it to set so that if N/A is displayed in cell C28, it states "No Data Yet". As it stands, if there's nothing there, it displays "Obese".

The rest of the formula works awesomely. I just dont know why it's throwing Obese in a non numeric value :/

Any help?

Comment: And by the way, your last IF should probably be `IF (C28 > 25%` instead of 26% otherwise, values from 25% to just under 26% won't have a result.  (Either that, or the one before it should be 26%.)

Comment: "I just dont know why it's throwing Obese..." The reason your existing code returns "Obese" is that the value being tested (which is #N/A) does not fit any of the conditions.  #N/A is not lower than 5%, not lower than 13%, not lower than 17%, not lower than 25%, and not greater than or equal to 26%.  Thus the results of each IF is FALSE, so you get "No Data Yet"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another IF to your statement to check for N/A:

```
=IF(ISNA(C28),"No Data Yet", IF(C28<=5%,"Body Builder", IF(C28<13%,"Athletic", IF(C28<17%,"Fit", IF(C28<25%,"Average", IF(C28>=26%,"Obese","No Data Yet"))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

may I suggest using a vlookup for clarity?

```
=iferror(vlookup(C28, BodyFatTable, 2, True), "No Data Yet")
```

here is what table would look like with two columns (adjust numbers to represent the LOWEST body fat % for each level (they need to be in order)) and then name this table BodyFatTable to have a nice named range in your formula

```
  0    Body Builder
.05    Athletic
.13    Fit
.17    Average
.25    Obese
```